# How can I use a clipping mask on a pen tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pen-tool

I used the pen tool to make a basic graphic in foreground. Then created a background using the blend tool with three different colors.

[image]

[source1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQG3D.jpg)

Then with both objects I made a clipping masks and it looks like this.

[image]

[source 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duKep.jpg)

Instead of the clipping mask occurring on the line it is somehow being created in between the lines. This problem seems basic but for some reason I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: It looks like an open path and the "strikeout" is an auto-attempt to close the path for the mask. Try converting the text to an outline (rather than a stroked path) before making the clipping mask?

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Just went to object>path>outline stroke

Answer (score 3):

Upgraded from a comment:

It looks like an open path and the "strikeout" is an auto-attempt to close the path for the mask. Try converting the text to an outline (rather than a stroked path) before making the clipping mask?